# ImageMagick create scaled thumbnail - command line

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to get ImageMagick to convert an image for me (command line linux) what I have is:

- User uploads image.
- I convert this image to a jpg

**NEXT STEP**

- Create a thumbnail of specific sizes without loosing proportions
- Eventually I will be adding in user controls to add effects etc etc

**For now** however all I need to do is take an image of any size and scale it to 320 x 320 giving it a black background - or a background colour of choice eventually!

Thanks for any advice / help - trying to find what I need has been impossible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way with some playing :

```
convert filein.jpg -trim -resize 320x320 -background black -gravity center -extent 320x320 fileout.jpg
```

If you **JUST** want to scall leave out the `-extent 320x320` and `-background black` as you wont have a background.

Answer (score 1):

Great examples under the [Thumbnails usage guide](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/).

```
convert -define jpeg:size=320x320 source_file.jpg \
      -thumbnail '320x320>' \
      -background black -gravity center -extent 320x320  outfile.gif
```

Comment: Similar but which is better I am not sure? Your answer or my own :P **I want to make sure the quality is kept as much as possible!!**

Comment: The define `jpeg:size` helps, but not needed. In terms of quality, both are the same.